# Add data and get data to FieldValue.arrayUnion in Flutter with Cloud FireStore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get the data structure similar to the data in the list from the TextEditingController and add data it to Firebase. Also how do I get data from Firebase and show it on the screen.
Thank you for your help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOeJB.png)

I saved firebase via onPressed, I brought all the data with get method via onPressed. However, I could not fetch a single data from FieldValue.array data as value Key.

```
final docData = {

  "list": [
    {
      "id": "data1",
      "amount1": "2000",
    },
    {
      "id": "data2",
      "amount1": "2500",
    },
    {
      "id": "data3",
      "amount1": "3500",
    }
  ],
};
```

final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

db
.collection("data")
.doc('one')
.set(docData)
.onError((e, _) => print("Error writing document: $e"));

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
db
.collection("data")
.orderBy('list', descending: true)
.get()
.then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
print(' ${element.data()}');
});
```

Comment: Kindly, please add tried code.

Comment: @AlpaguBurda Don't put code in comments please. Instead click the `edit` link under your question, add the code in there, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.